# T-SQL USE satetement in condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

It seems that USE statement is compiled by MS SQL Server 2008R2.

For example,

```
if(1=0)
begin
   USE MyDB
end
```

The result will be in executing `USE MyDB` while ignoring IF statement.

How can it be changed to work with condition?

P.S. Also tried `execute sp_executesql N'USE [MyDB]'`, it works with condition, but it does not change current context.

Comment: I don't see that. `USE master;if(1=0)begin USE tempdb end select db_name()` doesn't change the context to `tempdb`

Comment: The problem is in compiling the script with non existing DB,
try 'USE NonExistingDb'

Comment: Ah I see an issue. If both `master` and `tempdb` have a table of the same name but with different column names it compiles the batch as though the `USE` statement will be executed against the schema in `tempdb` and so can fail with a compile error.

Comment: When you need a condition Use MyDB, I would look at sqlcmd and variables.  Use $(DatabaseName) GO            http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx        That's the only way I have found to get "dynamic" Use MyDatabase names.

Comment: @granadacoder: it is a good way to do, we have been used it already.
I think there is no positive answer right now. Your comment is the most closed to answer, so repost it and it will be marked as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need a conditional "Use MyDB", I would look at sqlcmd and variables.

```
Use $(DatabaseName) 
GO
```

That's the only way I have found to get "dynamic" Use MyDatabase names.

Reference article:

[technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the correct way to change databases at runtime is precisely dynamic SQL, which is not compiled or validated until it's actually executed. Your sample, failing code involving `sp_executesql` in fact DOES change the context, but the gotcha is that the change lives **only** for the dynamic SQL batch, not on the calling code. To actually see and use that database, further code must be put **inside** the dynamic SQL block, and executed at once by `EXEC`/`sp_executesql`:

```
USE master ;
EXEC (N'USE tempdb ; PRINT db_name() ;') ;
PRINT db_name() ;
```

If you absolutely need to do that dynamic database switch, I think you can refactor the script to make it only build a string containing the commands to run, and that `1=0` condition only prepend a proper `USE` statement to choose a database to work with.

Comment: exactly, it is working in dynamic command scope, the question is can we do it in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Dynamic SQL in this way :

```
EXEC ('USE [MyDB];')
```

Comment: This won't work except if all the remaining code is also in the dynamic SQL. The context is reset as soon as the dynamic SQL exits.