# EXEC to USE Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a script that generates a database backup file name, backs up the database, and then restores it as a copy with the new database name. The name is based on some date/time data.

I then need to `USE` that database, in the script, and then disable all triggers.

However, this doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @Use VARCHAR(50)
SET @Use = 'USE ' + @NewDatabaseName

EXEC(@Use)
```

Running it manually - the database doesn't get 'USED'.

How can I execute the `USE` statement with a variable?

I have tried the `sp_executesql` proc as well, with the same result. Database didn't change.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'USE ' + @NewDatabaseName

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Looks like I might need to go into sqlcmd mode? Really hoping not to, though.

Comment: you need use sp_executesql

Comment: I was looking at that, but it seems it needs a few parameters, and I'm battling to understand what they would be, in the case of a 'USE' statement.

Comment: Just wondering: is your `based on some date/time data` database name is greater than 46 characters?

Comment: No, the DB name is 8 chars long.

Comment: Use `GO`after `USE <dbname>`?

Comment: `SET @sqlCommand = 'USE ' + @NewDatabaseName +'GO'`

Comment: Tried that. SET @sqlCommand = N'USE Carepay GO' - but still, DB stays as 'master'.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160233/t-sql-use-satetement-in-condition) - sqlcmd may be the best way to go, otherwise you'd have to execute everything in the same `exec` command, rather than having multiple commands.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969046/in-sql-server-is-there-any-way-to-get-the-use-database-command-to-accept-a-var

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both `exec` and `execute_sql` run in their own scope.  And the change in database will only affect their own scope.  So you could:

```
set @sql = 'use ' + quotename(@new_db_name) + '; disable trigger t1;'
exec (@sql)
```

As far as I know, there is no way to change the database context of the current scope to a variable database name.

Comment: Yup, do it all in one EXEC. Just did that after seeing your initial answer. Thanks. Learnt something now.