# SQL Server stored procedure to Restore from Database backup file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-restore

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server designed to restore a database from a backup file created from a different server. It dynamically constructs statement to restore from a backup file on disk, create a new user in the database (because it's being restored to a different server), authorize the user in two different schemas, assign the user to two separate roles, and then drop the old user (from the old database on the other server).

The stored procedure code is below (sorry it's so long), but so I could test it, I added a flag parameter (`@exec bit = 0`) to control whether it actually executed the SQL statements it generated, or just printed them out. If you pass @exec = 1 it executes the SQL, but if not, it just prints them out so I can run them separately to test the dynamic SQL code generation. Since the stored procedure code calls restore, and you cannot restore the current database, it has to be run from another database on the same server, but in the stored procedure, after it executes the `Restore`, it switches the current DB to the newly restored database to execute the remaining SQL statements. The SQL statements it constructs are as follows:

```
Restore Database [newDBName]
from disk = N'\\BTSSqlTest1\lien_refreshes\BackUps\LASDB.1.31s100.bak'  
with File = 1,
move N'lasdb' to N'E:\lien_refreshes\SQLData\newDBName.mdf',
move N'lasdb_log' to N'E:\lien_refreshes\SQLData\newDBName.ldf',
NoUnload, Replace, Stats = 25;


Use [newDBName]

Create User [domain\NewUserName]

Grant execute to [domain\NewUserName]

Alter Authorization On Schema::[db_backupoperator] to [domain\NewUserName]

Alter Authorization On Schema::[db_Owner] to [domain\NewUserName]

sp_AddRolemember 'db_backupoperator', domain\NewUserName'

sp_AddRolemember 'db_owner', domain\NewUserName'

sp_DropUser [domain\OldUserName]
```

When I run these statements separately in SQL Server Enterprise Manager, it all works as designed.

When I run the stored procedure with `@exec=1`, it executes each of these statements individually using `Exec ([SQL])`. However, although everything appears to complete successfully except for the Drop User statement, which throws an error

> User does not exist in database

Results from running the stored procedure:

```
25 percent processed. 
50 percent processed. 
75 percent processed. 
100 percent processed. 
Processed 779144 pages for database 'newDBName', file 'lasdb' on file 1.
Processed 6 pages for database 'newDBName', file 'lasdb_log' on file 1. 
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 779150 pages in 11.532 seconds (527.845 MB/sec). 
Database [newDBName] restored. 
Switched to Database [newDBName]. 
Execute granted to user [domain\NewUserName]. 
User [domain\NewUserName] authorized in schema db_backupoperator. 
User [domain\NewUserName] authorized in schema db_Owner. 
User [domain\NewUserName] added to role db_backupoperator. 
User [domain\NewUserName] added to role db_Owner. 
Msg 15008, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropuser, Line 12 
User domain\OldUserName' does not exist in the current database. 
Dropped User [domain\OldUserName].
```

When I look at the resulting database itself, (even after a refresh) the newly created user is not in the database, and the old user from the other server is still there.

```
 ******************************************************
 ****** Stored proc ***********************************
 Create PROCEDURE RestoreProdTest
 @fileSpec nvarchar(400), 
 @exec bit = 0
 As
 Set NoCount On
 declare @nl Char(2) = char(13) + char(10)
 declare @2nl char(4) = @nl + @nl
 -- --------------------------------
 declare @debugMsg varchar(max) = 'Variable Values:' + @nl
 declare @sqlCode varchar(max) = 'Executable SQL Code:' + @nl

   declare @dbNm nvarchar(50) = 'newDBName' 
   declare @user varchar(40) = 'domain\NewUserName' 
   declare @dbId int = DB_Id(@dbNm)
   -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
   Declare @tab Table 
          (logNm varchar(256), phyNm varchar(300), 
        Typ varchar, FilGrpNm varChar(128), Siz varchar(128), 
           MaxSize varChar(128), FileId varchar(128), 
           CreateLSN varChar(128), 
           DropLSN varchar(128), UniqueId varChar(128), 
           ROLSN varchar(128), 
           RWLSN varchar(128), BkSizBytes varChar(128), 
           SrceBlckSize varchar(128), 
           FileGrpId varchar(128), LogGrpId varChar(128), 
           DiffBaseLSN varchar(128), 
           DiffBaseGUID varchar(128), IsReadOnly varChar(128), 
           IsPresent varchar(128), ThumbPrint varchar(128)) 
   -- ----------------------------------------------------------
   Insert @tab(logNm, phyNm, Typ, FilGrpNm, Siz, MaxSize, FileId, 
          CreateLSN, DropLSN, UniqueId, ROLSN, RWLSN, BkSizBytes, 
          SrceBlckSize, FileGrpId, LogGrpId, DiffBaseLSN, 
          DiffBaseGUID, IsReadOnly, IsPresent, ThumbPrint)
   Exec('Restore fileListOnly from disk=''' + @fileSpec + '''')
   declare @oldDataFileSpec varChar(400),
           @oldLogFileSpec  varChar(400)
   Set @oldDataFileSpec = (Select logNm from @tab where Typ = 'D')
   Set @oldLogFileSpec  = (Select logNm from @tab where Typ = 'L')
   -- -------------------------------------
   declare @dataFile varChar(400)
   declare @logFile varChar(400)
   Select @dataFile = physical_name
   from sys.Master_Files 
   Where Database_Id = @dbId and type = 0
   Select @logFile = physical_name
   from sys.Master_Files
   Where Database_Id = @dbId and type = 1

   declare @killSql nVarChar(200) = 'msdb.dbo.sp_KillUserProc '  

   declare @restoreSql nVarChar(1000) = 
          N'Restore Database [' + @dbNm + ']' + @nl + 
          'from disk = N''' + @fileSpec + ''' with File = 1,' + @nl +
          '   move N''' + @oldDataFileSpec + '''' + ' to N''' + 
              @dataFile + ''',' + @nl +
          '   move N''' + @oldLogFileSpec  + '''' + ' to N'''  + 
              @logFile + ''',' + @nl +
          '   NoUnload, Replace, Stats = 25;'


   declare @spids table (spid integer primary key not null)
   insert @spids(spid)
   select session_id from sys.dm_exec_sessions
   where database_id = @dbId
   -- ----------------------
   declare @spid int = 0
   declare @spidstr varchar(4)
   while exists (select * from @spids where spid > @spid) begin
          Select @spid = min(spid) from @spids where spid > @spid
          set @spidstr = format(@spid, '0')
          set @sqlCode += @killSql + @spidstr + @nl
   end
   -- --------------------------------------------

   if @exec = 1 Begin 
          Set @spid = 0
          while exists (select * from @spids where spid > @spid) begin
                 Select @spid = min(spid) from @spids where spid > @spid
                 set @spidstr = format(@spid, '0')
                 exec(@killSql + @spidstr)
          end
          -- ------------------------------------------------
          exec (@restoreSql)
          print ' Database [' + @dbNm + '] restored.'
   end
   else Set @sqlCode += @restoreSql + @2nl 

   -- Switch to new restored database
   declare @UseSql nVarChar(100) = 'Use [' + @dbNm + ']'
   if @exec = 1 begin
          exec (@UseSql) 
          print 'Switched to Database [' + @dbNm + '].'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @UseSql + @2nl

   -- Grant execute permissions (also creates the user)
   declare @grantSql nVarChar(1000) = N'Grant execute to [{User}]'
   Set @grantSql = Replace(@grantSql, '{User}', @user)
   if @exec = 1  begin
          exec (@grantSql) 
          print 'Execute granted to user [' + @user + '].'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @grantSql + @2nl

   -- Assign user to schemas -------------
   declare @schmSql nVarChar(200) = 
          N'Alter Authorization On Schema::[db_backupoperator] to [{user}]'
   Set @schmSql = Replace(@schmSql, '{User}', @user)
   if @exec = 1 begin
          exec (@schmSql) 
          print 'User [' + @user + '] authrzd in schema db_backupoperator.'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @schmSql + @2nl
   -- ----------------------------
   Set @schmSql = Replace(@schmSql, 'db_backupoperator', 'db_Owner')
   if @exec = 1 begin
          exec (@schmSql) 
          print 'User [' + @user + '] authorized in schema db_Owner.'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @schmSql + @2nl
   -- --------------------------------------------------

   -- Grant backup operator & dbOwner Roles 
   declare @roleSql nVarChar(1000) = 
          'sp_AddRolemember ''db_backupoperator'', ''{User}''' 
   Set @roleSql = Replace(@roleSql, '{User}', @user)
   if @exec = 1 begin
          exec (@roleSql) 
          print 'User [' + @user + '] added to role db_backupoperator.'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @roleSql + @2nl
   -- ---------------------------
   set @roleSql = 'sp_AddRolemember ''db_owner'', ''{User}''' 
   Set @roleSql = Replace(@roleSql, '{User}', @user)
   if @exec = 1 begin
          exec (@roleSql) 
          print 'User [' + @user + '] added to role db_Owner.'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @roleSql + @2nl

   -- ----- Drop PROD User -----------
   declare @dropUserSql nVarchar(50) = 
          'sp_DropUser [rose\LasPROD_Svc]' 
   if @exec = 1 begin
          exec (@dropUserSql) 
          print 'Dropped User [rose\LasPROD_Svc].'
   end else Set @sqlCode += @dropUserSql + @2nl
   -- ---------------------------
   if @exec = 0 print @sqlCode
   Return 0
```

Comment: `EXEC (@sql)` runs that SQL in it's own scope, it doesn't change the current database for the following commands.

Comment: @DavidG, so how can I run the remaining commands in the newly restored database? Most of these command only run "in the current database" and do not seem to have a syntactical variant to execute in another database (like a select can by using a fully qualified name (`Database.Schema.Object`). Is there another way to execute these so that they are executed against the newly restored database?

Comment: Well you can test it out by running `PRINT DB_NAME()`, that will show you which database context it is running in. I believe the only way you could do the above would be run run everything from `USE...` to the end as a single statement.

Comment: @DavidG, I can think of one option, which is to dynamically construct a complete Stored proc with al the statements in it, create this new SOPP In the newly restored database, and then execute it using it's fully qualified name. That might work, but I would then need to drop it when it finished.

Comment: Making it all one statement might work, I would need to put "Go"s in between all of them then.... I will try that. If rep matter to you, please add this as an answer and I will mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I think this is a [dupe anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615901/exec-to-use-database)?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity. The issue that your asking about is: "When I look at the resulting database itself, (even after a refresh) the newly created user is not in the database, and the old user from the other server is still there." Meaning you are unable to delete and or create users in the newly created DB?
This might be a  (security) restriction imposed by MS. I would try to create or  otherwise  an error recognizing the named instance of your schema.

I would separate out the User Creation to another process.

Comment: @DaniDev, No I can manually create and drop the users. The issue is I have to log on twice a week and do this. I was trying to automate the process from a stored proc. If you're interested, the problem I am trying to solve is the need to refresh the data in Development and Test environments from Production twice a week, but retain the other environmental-specific properties of those databases.

Comment: Yes that is what I understood. My comment wasn't clear enough. What I am suggesting is that you run the user delete/create in a separate subsequent context where you can confirm the schema has been created.

Answer (score 0):

"USE db_name" whould be included for every EXEC call.

Or run the scripts as one large script rather than multiple scripts.