# USE [mydatabase] with a variable in script does not work

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get specific tables from all databases that are running on our SQL Server and insert them into a temporary table.

```
+----------------|----------|-------|------------+
| ServerInstance | Database | Table | Created on |
+----------------|----------|-------|------------+
| Instance01     | DB1      |TB1    |2020.01.01  |
+----------------|----------|-------|------------+
| Instance01     | DB2      |TB3    |2020.01.01  |
+----------------|----------|-------|------------+
| ...            | ...      |...    |...         |
+----------------|----------|-------|------------+
```

The problem I have now is that this block

```sql
SET @sql_db = 'use ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName);
EXEC sp_executesql 
   @sql_db;
```

seems not to change the database for the rest of the code. As a result I only get the tables in which database im currently active listed for all databases.

Can someone help me please!?

Thx
Alex

Here is the complete code:

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @sql_db NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @dbStatus NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @create_date DATE;
    DECLARE @result TABLE
    (
                          [instance] NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        , [database] NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        , [table]    NVARCHAR(MAX)
                        , [created]  DATE
    );
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global' , 'cursor_db') >= -1
        BEGIN
            DEALLOCATE myCursor;
    END;
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global' , 'cursor_table') >= -1
        BEGIN
            DEALLOCATE myCursor;
    END;
    -- Cursor zum auslesen aller Datenbanken inkl. Status (Äusserer Cursor)
    DECLARE cursor_db CURSOR
    FOR SELECT 
               name
             , d.state_desc
        FROM   sys.databases d
        WHERE  name NOT IN ('master' , 'model' , 'msdb' , 'tempdb')
        AND d.name NOT LIKE '%refere%';
    OPEN cursor_db;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_db INTO @dbName
                                 , @dbStatus;
    WHILE @@fetch_Status = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql_db = 'use ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName);
            EXECUTE sp_executesql 
                 @sql_db;

            --Innerer Cursor zum auslesen der Tabellen
            DECLARE cursor_table CURSOR
            FOR SELECT 
                       t.name
                     , t.create_date
                FROM   sys.tables t
                WHERE  t.type = 'u'
                       AND t.name LIKE '%bak%';
            OPEN cursor_table;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_table INTO @tableName
                                            , @create_date;
            WHILE @@fetch_Status = 0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @result
                    (
                           instance
                         , [database]
                         , [table]
                         , created
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                           @@serverName , 
                           @dbName , 
                           @tableName , 
                           @create_date
                    );
                    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_table INTO @tableName
                                                    , @create_date;
                END;
            CLOSE cursor_table;
            DEALLOCATE cursor_table;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_db INTO @dbName
                                         , @dbStatus;
        END;
    CLOSE cursor_db;
    DEALLOCATE cursor_db;
    SELECT 
           *
    FROM   @result r
    ORDER BY 
             2;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
           ERROR_NUMBER() AS   ErrorNumber
         , ERROR_MESSAGE() AS  ErrorMessage
         , ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
         , ERROR_STATE() AS    ErrorState
         , ERROR_LINE() AS     ErrorLine;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: You can't use `USE` like that: `sp_executesql` runs in its own context, so `USE` only updates _that_ context's current database, not the current context. You need to put **all** of your SQL in the `sp_executesql` string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EXEC to USE Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615901/exec-to-use-database)

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution that exactly does what I wanted. This version is much shorter and without any cursors. Did not know that it is possible to use `EXEC` command for `Insert`.

THX everyone for help!

Here is the full code:

```sql
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @dbStatus NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @create_date DATE;

DECLARE @result TABLE
(
                      [instance] NVARCHAR(MAX)
                    , [database] NVARCHAR(MAX)
                    , [table]    NVARCHAR(MAX)
                    , [created]  DATE
);

SET @sql = '
USE [?]
SELECT 
      @@serverName
    , DB_NAME()
    , t.name
    , t.create_date
FROM   sys.tables t
WHERE  t.type = ''u''
    AND t.create_date < GETDATE() - 60
    AND t.name LIKE ''%bak%'';'

INSERT INTO @result
(
       instance
     , [database]
     , [table]
     , created
)
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
     @sql;

SELECT 
       *
FROM   @result r;
```